# How can I interpret a string that contains decimal escape sequences?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to parse the "parsable" ouput of the [avahi-browse](https://linux.die.net/man/1/avahi-browse) command for use in a shell script. e.g.

```sh
for i in $(avahi-browse -afkpt | awk -F';' '{print $4}') ; do <do something with $i> ; done
```

The output looks like:

```
+;br.vlan150;IPv4;Sonos-7828CAC5D944\064Bedroom;_sonos._tcp;local
```

I am particularly interested in the value of the 4th field, which is a "service name".

With the `-p|--parsable` flag, `avahi-browse` escapes the "service name" values.

For example `7828CAC5D944\064Bedroom`, where `\064` is a zero-padded decimal representation of the ASCII character '@'.

I just want `7828CAC5D944@Bedroom` so I can, for example, use it as an argument to another command.

I can't quite figure out how to do this inside the shell.

I tried using `printf`, but that only seems to interpret octal escape sequences. e.g.:

```sh
# \064 is interpreted as 4
$ printf '%b\n' '7828CAC5D944\064Bedroom'
7828CAC5D9444Bedroom
```

How can I parse these values, converting any of the decimal escape sequences to their corresponding ASCII characters?

Comment: if you remove the `-p` flag will that replace `\064` with `@`? can you confirm that you also want to remove the leading string `Sonos-` (or is that any string up to a `-`)?

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- there's a reason the `-p` flag cannot be removed (will removing `-p` generate a `@` instead of `\064`?)
- the 4th field is to be further processed by stripping off all text up to and including a hyphen (`-`)
- `\064` is the only escaped decimal value we need to worry about (for now)

Since OP is already calling `awk` to process the raw data I propose we do the rest of the processing in the same `awk` call.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F';' '
{ n=split($4,arr,"-")         # split field #4 based on a hyphen delimiter
  gsub(/\\064/,"@",arr[n])    # perform the string replacement in the last arr[] entry
  print arr[n]                # print the newly modified string
}'

# or as a one-liner:

awk -F';' '{n=split($4,arr,"-");gsub(/\\064/,"@",arr[n]);print arr[n]}'
```

Simulating the `avahi-browse` call feeding into `awk`:

```
echo '+;br.vlan150;IPv4;Sonos-7828CAC5D944\064Bedroom;_sonos._tcp;local' | 
awk -F';' '{n=split($4,arr,"-");gsub(/\\064/,"@",arr[n]);print arr[n]}'
```

This generates:

```
7828CAC5D944@Bedroom
```

And for the main piece of code I'd probably opt for a `while` loop, especially if there's a chance the `avahi-browse/awk` process could generate data with white space:

```
while read -r i
do
    <do something with $i> 
done < <(avahi-browse -afkpt | awk -F';' '{n=split($4,arr,"-");gsub(/\\064/,"@",arr[n]);print arr[n]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` to do the conversion:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/\\(\d+)/chr $1/ge' <<<"7828CAC5D944\064Bedroom"
7828CAC5D944@Bedroom
```

As part of your larger script, completely replacing `awk`:

```sh
while read -r i; do
    # do something with i
done < <(avahi-browse -afkpt | perl -F';' -lane 'print $F[3] =~ s/\\(\d+)/chr $1/ger')
```